# Extracting values from aapt output in Windows

Tags: android, cmd

I am working with Windows 8. So kindly do not give any linux commands. I am really struggling to extract package name and versionCode from my aapt output. It comes in the following format in cmd.

```
       package: name='com.brand0.subbranded.monkey' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0'
```

I used the following command :

```
      D:\android-studio-.3.2\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt d badging SubBranded-monkeytalk.apk | grep package
```

The otherwise help available is with the "awk command" which is not recognized or sed command which is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure (and ugly) single line cmd solution:

```
for /f "delims=' tokens=2,4" %a in ('D:\android-studio-.3.2\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt d badging SubBranded-monkeytalk.apk ^| findstr "package"') do @echo Package name is %a && @echo Version code is %b
```

If you need to put this in a batch file instead, you need to double the % signs for the variables, and you can format the statements a little more nicely:

```
set AAPT=D:\android-studio-.3.2\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt
for /f "delims=' tokens=2,4" %%a in ('%AAPT% d badging SubBranded-monkeytalk.apk ^| findstr "package"') do (
    echo Package name is %%a
    echo Version code is %%b
)
```

This is fairly fragile and (IMO) even harder to understand than sed.  You would be well served to install Cygwin and learn a little about sed.  Once you understand it (and it won't take long) you will never go back.

Example making use of variables to store the results:

```
set AAPT=D:\android-studio-.3.2\sdk\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt
for /f "delims=' tokens=2,4" %%a in ('%AAPT% d badging SubBranded-monkeytalk.apk ^| findstr "package"') do (
    set PKGNAME=%%a
    set PKGVER=%%b
)
echo Package name is %PKGNAME%, version is %PKGVER%
```

As mentioned below, if you attempt to set and then reference a non-loop variable inside the for loop, cmd.exe processes the entire for loop as one command.  This unfortunately expands `%BLAH%` before executing the loop, so the results come out with unexpected values.  You can work around that with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and referencing the variables with `!BLAH!` instead of `%BLAH%`.  This is sometimes useful if you need to get substrings inside the loop, but in this case with only one value inside the loop, you can just fall through and do your work afterwards.

Comment: I can echo the Package name, but cannot set a variable for /f "delims=' tokens=2,4" %%a in ('%AAPT% d badging SubBranded-monkeytalk.apk ^| findstr "package"') do (
    echo Package name is %%a
    echo Version code is %%b
)

Comment: You set a variable in place of the echo lines... e.g. set pkgname=%%a

Comment: i figured it out, apparently, you have to do something like  set  "PACKAGENAME=%%a" setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    echo Package name is !PACKAGENAME! otherwise, set PACKAGENAME=%%a is itself a DOS command and it shows blank.

Comment: That's only true if you want to use the variable you've set INSIDE the for loop.  If you instead just use the loop to set it, you can use the variable afterwards just fine.  Adding code to these comments is poor, so I'll add a quick example to the answer.